# Android, disable the swiping to interact with SlidingPaneLayout

Tags: android

I need to disable swiping to open/close SlidingPaneLayout because my main view is a map.
I'll open/close it using a button.

Comment: Hi, how have you achieve the problem? Can share the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Subclass `SlidingPaneLayout`, override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and make it always return `false`. This will prevent `SlidingPaneLayout` from handling touch events.

See http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html for more information.

**Update**:
If touch events are not handled by the child view(s), the `SlidingPaneLayout`'s `onTouchEvent()` method will be called nevertheless. To completely disable handling touch events also override `onTouchEvent()` and always return `false`.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}
```

**Note:** The downside of this approach is that touch events still get dispatched to the second child view when it's only partly visible. So you might want to check out the other answers.

Comment: I think it should return true but not false.

Comment: @GMsoF it should return false.

Comment: If **onInterceptTouchEvent()** returns false, **onTouchEvent()** won't be called. According to your link. But i didn't test it.

And the problem of this approach(as far as i know) is that when left pane is open, you can close it only by pressing back key.

I think, **quicksilver**'s solution is the right answer

Answer (score 10):

This one is a bit tricky. If you always return true in `onInterceptTouchEvent()` it will dispatch event to the hidden content below. I was able to achieve it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return !slidingEnabled || super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (!slidingEnabled) {
        // Careful here, view might be null
        getChildAt(1).dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Without returning false in onTouchEvent You can still open menu with clicking on the edge of the screen.

Comment: This code dispatches TouchEvents only to the right pane (second child). If you want both panes to stay interactive, use something like this inside onTouchEvent: `if (!getChildAt(0).dispatchTouchEvent(ev)) getChildAt(1).dispatchTouchEvent(ev);`. It dispatches to the right pane if the left does not handle an event.

Comment: where is  slidingEnabled  ?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to disable the 'drag to open' event and enable user input once the layout is opened, you can use this

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {

    if(!isOpen()) return false;

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0);
}
```

Comment: Works Perfectly..!!

Answer (score 1):

Building on Roman Zhilichs answer with two improvements.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return !swipeEnabled || super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (!swipeEnabled) {
        if (!getChildAt(0).dispatchTouchEvent(ev)) {
            ev.offsetLocation(-getChildAt(0).getWidth(),0);
            getChildAt(1).dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

First, this tries to dispatch the MotionEvent to the first child before dispatching it to the second. This way, both child views stay interactive. Second, MotionsEvents dispatched to the second child view must be offset by the width of the first view. This assumes that the sliding pane slides in from the left, as is usual with SlidingPaneLayout.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the touchlistener and return true, it will consume the touch event and the widget will not handle it further.

```
slidingPaneLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but in case anyone wanted to how to go around this without overriding nothing, you just want to set the width of the layout menu's `layoutParams` to zero.

`binding.clMenu.layoutParams.width = 0` where `clMenu` is the first layout declared within `SlidingPaneLayout`.