# How to keep SlidingPaneLayout opened in android?

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

There is slidingPaneLayout, which I need to keep opened.
First I tried to don use panelsidelistener, but it didn't work
Then I tried to set `spl.openPane()` that is also failed because it opened for some percents and opened again.

So I need to know how to keep it opened and deny slide it via touch?

Similar Posts Found But I Didn't Solve my problem. Sliding menu used in Activity class.

Comment: Here is another thread with similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002466/android-disable-the-swiping-to-interact-with-slidingpanelayout

Comment: i tried but didn't solve problem , what should i do ? i sliodingPaneLayout in activity class and didn't use class extends viewgroup